# Element not showing up after UItableviewCell SubClass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im using Custome uitableview cell to avoid performance drop.

this is how i fill my table cell :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *reuseIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell_%ld",(long)indexPath.row];

    SubcategoryTableViewCell * sctvCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (sctvCell == nil) {
        sctvCell= [[SubcategoryTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    }
    sctvCell.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        [sctvCell.label setText:appRecord.title];
    return sctvCell;

}
```

in my "SubcategoryTableViewCell.h" header with IBOutlet to item in cell:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mood_count_lbl;
```

and in my "SubcategoryTableViewCell.m" class :

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

}
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if(self){

        self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        UIView *whiteRoundedCornerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,150)];
        whiteRoundedCornerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
        [whiteRoundedCornerView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1);
        whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;  
        [self.contentView addSubview:whiteRoundedCornerView];
        [self.contentView sendSubviewToBack:whiteRoundedCornerView];



        return self;

    }
```

with above code noting shows up in cell except the boarder and shadow that i

made in custome cell.

also the element in on cell are correctly connected to custome cell.

is the problem goes back to dynamic "reuseIdentifier" that i made ?

if i change it back to this code everything works well without custome cell customization and subclassing:

```
NSString *reuseIdentifier = @"PlaceholderCell2";
UITableViewCell * sctvCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

if (sctvCell == nil) {
    sctvCell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

}
```

even if i change my code like this :

```
self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIView *whiteRoundedCornerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,300,150)];
whiteRoundedCornerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0;
[whiteRoundedCornerView.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor grayColor].CGColor];
whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1);
whiteRoundedCornerView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;  
[self.contentView addSubview:whiteRoundedCornerView];
UILabel *_lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
[self.contentView addSubview:_lblTitle];
[self.contentView sendSubviewToBack:whiteRoundedCornerView];
```

new label now shows up.

im checking the cell name and class and everything is ok.

[image]

my "SubCategoryViewController.m" code : http://paste2.org/_nCY8zF9w

my "SubcategoryTableViewCell.m" code :http://paste2.org/_h9AJnzcV

my "SubcategoryTableViewCell.h" code :http://paste2.org/_vUJjEcXV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting text to `sctvCell.label`, what is this label? You also have `label` with tag value 1. Which label do you want to use?

Assuming you want to use the label with the tag and the function `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier`, you should add the label in this function, then set text to this label. `reuseIdentifier` is dynamic, which should be static. You need only one identifier for your cell.

Assuming you want to use the `IBoutlet` label, then you are loading cells from xib or storyboard, as for iOS 8, if you have setup a cell in your table with reuseIdentifier, the cell loaded from storyboard will always has value, so it can't be nil. You might want to add your customise code to `awakeFromNib` method in your cell subclass.

Comment: thanks for answer  and sorry for mistype. the tag version was from old one.
im using Iboutlet that connected to custome cell header.
im compiling for ios 7.1+.
in my costume cell class im not using any kinda xib.

Comment: Then you can use the latter method.

Comment: due to ur suggestion i moved my "-(id)initWithStyle" to "- (void)awakeFromNib"  now nothing shows on my table even the boarder that i made.

Comment: You probably forget  set the cell class in storyboard to your cell class.

Comment: my cell are set to use that custome class. if i remove it no cell will appear. fun part is if i add new label code inside my customiziation it doesent appear too. i update my question.

Comment: Did you set identifier for cell in storyboard?

Comment: yes   my identifier is set. in my question if i use second method that i mention everything works well without custome cell.

Comment: Actually the same code worked for me, did you set height for the rows?

Comment: no hope. :(
i even removed the height part.
one thing is even if i remove the prototype cell of table and set to 0 or set them back to 1 none of cell item shows up.

Comment: If you could you can share your code somewhere, so that it will be resolved much quicker, I suspect something is not set up right.

Comment: thanks for help. ive added my code end of my question

Comment: I see that in your code the `NSString *reuseIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell_%ld",(long)indexPath.row];`, it should never be dynamic, you have only one type of cell, please use only one reuseIdentifier for it. Just set it to be what you have defined in storyboard so that you get the exact same type of cell from storyboard.